# Django django-user-accounts blank template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, pinax

I have followed the [instructions](https://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for installing and setting up [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts). However I have a problem with the templates. When I try to access the views such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/settings/ I'm shown a template that just contains `{# This template intentionally left blank to satisfy test suites. Your project should always provide a site_base.html itself. #}`

I've tried to add a site_base.html to templates but it has no effect. I've tried the both the main app and in separate `account` directory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned out I had to delete `pinax_theme_bootstrap` from installed apps in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the django-user-account app but what I can see in the docs the template directory for each one of the actions is:

```
account/login.html
account/logout.html
account/signup.html
account/signup_closed.html
...
```

You can see more [here](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/blob/master/docs/templates.rst)

Did you try to create this files? Then these files can extend from a base.html.

Comment: And have you solved or is it still not the solution?

Comment: It didn't change anything. So no, it's still not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. Removing pinax from `INSTALLED_APPS` did get rid of the error, but I actually still want pinax so I had to look a little further for the root of the issue. For me the root of the issue was that I had just split up my `settings.py` into [separate modules for various environments](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#SimplePackageOrganizationforEnvironments) which are all housed in a `settings` directory. This caused my `PROJECT_ROOT` and `PACKAGE_ROOT` variables to be interpreted from `my_project/settings/base.py` instead of `my_project/settings.py`! So django thought that my templates directory was `my_project/settings/templates/`, and when it couldn't find `site_base.html` there it freaked out.

In my base settings I fixed the aforementioned variables to look one level up (from their previous location) everything went back to working:

```
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, os.pardir))
```